# lua table wrong loop order

Tags: loops, lua

I'm trying to loop a table in lua but the table loop order is wrong. The code below prints:

- key : three num: 3
- key : one num: 1
- key : two num: 2

And the code is:

```
  testNumbers =
  {
    one = 1,
    two = 2,
    three = 3
  }

for key,num in pairs(testNumbers) do 

print("key : " .. key .. " num: " .. num)

end
```

How can I make it loop in right order? I can't change the code too much as I need the key variable as it is now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For efficiency, Lua tables do not track the order of their keys. If you cannot change the format of your table, you can still enforce an iteration order by keeping an array of keys and iterating through that.

```
testNumbers =
  {
    one = 1,
    two = 2,
    three = 3
  }

local order = {'one', 'two', 'three'}

for _, key in ipairs(order) do
  print("key : " .. key .. " num: " .. testNumbers[key])
end
```

Comment: And with a bit of meta-magic, you can even hide that code to make it seem like you're only using a "normal" table ;)

Answer (score 4):

Tables in Lua are *sets*, not sequences, of key-value pairs.

Traversing a table visits its pairs in unspecified order. See the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-next).